# Contar registros de un Subformulario

Tags: ms-access

muy buenos días.
Espero que se encuentren muy bien.
Tengo un duda que no he podido solucionar, estoy realizando un proyecto en access, en este proyecto se lleva el registro de cambios de varios productos, cuenta como datos principales un Lote y Codigo de tipo de datos alfanumericos, en donde tengo duda es en este formulario donde tengo un formulario independiente para buscar informacion, dicha informacion se muestra en un subformulario en este subformulario es dependiente de una consulta o su origen es una consulta, todo funciona, si hago filtros del formulario padre el hijo se filtra, ahora lo que se me dificulta es que a partir del subformulario, me muestre un conteo de registros en el formulario principal como se ve en la imagen, dichos conteos se muestran en la parte inferior del formulario padre, lo que hice es en el subformulario hacer un metodo DCount y de ahi poner una caja de texto en el formulario padre para mostrar los datos del subformuario, asta aqui funciona, el detalle viene cuando intento hacer un filtro, lo hago pero el conteo se mantiene igual no cambia, ejemplo orita tengo 5 registros en total y si aparece los 5 pero cuando hago un filtro y queda dos registros en el subformulario no cambia los conteos siguen igual o con los datos si no tuviera filtros, lo que quisiera saber es como hacer un filtro y cambie el conteo en las cajas de texto del formulario principal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! considera redactar mejor la pregunta... y de paso, como es el codigo para obtener esa cuenta? cuando filtras, filtras tambien el conteo?

Comment: Muchas gracias por los consejos que me proporcionas!
En cuestiones del formulario el conteo lo realizo el la parte del pie del subformulario dentro de una caja de texto, donde su origen es el siguente:
=DCont("[Numero de Rachazos]","[NumerodeRechazos]") 
y asi con otras tres cajas de texto donde obtengo diferentes conteos.

Comment: En la parte del formulario principal el codigo para filtrar el subformulario es es siguiente:
Private Sub ConsultaDato2()
        Dim Consulta As String
        Consulta = " Codigo BETWEEN '" & Me.TXTCodigoInicial & "' AND '" & Me.TXTCodigoFinal & "'  "
        Me.SubformRechazos.Form.Filter = Consulta
        Me.SubformRechazos.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub

Comment: Todo el codigo en la pregunta por favor. Entonces DCont no te sirve... porque cuenta todo no? y vos queres la cuenta filtrada....

Comment: Exactamente lo que busco es que al abrir el formulario si me aparezca toda la cuenta de los registros y al hacer el filtro me reduzca el conteo a el numero de de registros filtrados, ejemplo al abrir como se muestra en la imagen tengo 5 registros y al hacer un filtro que me arroje 2 registros solo me muestre en el conteo 2 registros. que respete el numero de registros que aparece en subformulario

Comment: y leiste la documentacion de DCont? tiene para aplicar un filtro.. intentaste aplicarlo?

Comment: Leí la documentación de DCount y tiene como tal una clausula de filtro como un WHERE pero no me permite tomar los valores del formulario principal

Comment: Eso es lo que tenes que resolver, como pasarle parametros.. esa es tu pregunta, no todo esto ;)